# Refinery error when pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms, bamboo

I've a Refinery app, works great locally. 
Created a bamboo stack on Heroku.

When I try to push I can see this:

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Then I open it up in browser:
"We're sorry, but something went wrong."

$ heroku logs

```
Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/refinerycms-authentication-2.0.2/app/views/refinery/users/new.html.erb within refinery/layouts/login (82.3ms)
2012-03-15T14:43:25+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1269ms
```

full output is [here](https://gist.github.com/2044605)

Any help is great, thanks!

+++

Update:

Updated the stack to Cedar and made Ruby env 1.9.3

```
$ heroku config
DATABASE_URL        => ..
GEM_PATH            => vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
LANG                => en_US.UTF-8
PATH                => bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
RACK_ENV            => production
RAILS_ENV           => production
RUBY_VERSION        => ruby-1.9.3-p0
SHARED_DATABASE_URL => ..

$ heroku info --app mimacohuoncedar
=== mimacohuoncedar
Addons:        Basic Logging, Shared Database 5MB
Database Size: (empty)
Git URL:       git@heroku.com:mimacohuoncedar.git
Owner:         ..
Repo Size:     9M
Slug Size:     19M
Stack:         cedar
Web URL:       http://mimacohuoncedar.herokuapp.com/
```

$ heroku logs now shows this:
[this-updated](https://gist.github.com/2044605)

Where to go on? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont know if you managed to fix this but I ran into the same issue using the Cedar stack. Found this [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile/) on Heroku that seemed to do the trick for me. Ran the line in terminal and it pushed first time.

Comment: Thanks for help, finally gotit! Share because maybe others will have the same issue: had 3 problems: first I needed Cedar and _not_ Bamboo stack. Then I migrated the DB with "heroku run rake db:migrate". Finally I used the article you mentioned. Thanks a lot, it works now!

Answer (score 1):

That output looks suspiciously like Cedar stack and not Bamboo - give http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile a go. That should sort you out.

Comment: Thanks great! A lot ahead! but still have problems, updated the question+output.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing this same error, and the accepted answer did not solve it for me;

[This blog](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2012/02/heroku-and-rails-3-2-assetprecompile-error/) however, did the trick. The blog title refers to Rails 3.2, but I'm on 3.1 and was seeing this same error.

The blog recommended adding this line to `application.rb`.

`config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`

The meaning, as summarized from the article;

> This option prevents the Rails environment from being loaded when the assets:precompile task is executed. Because Heroku precompiles assets before setting the database configuration, you need to set this configuration to false or you Rails application will try to connect to an unexisting database.

Added the line and pushed, everything seems good now.